# Error. Expression must have a class type

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

I'm trying to pass a `Mat` to a function but I'm getting some errors when I try to get the `float` data of the image. Can someone enlighten me on what's wrong?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img;//gradients from fingerprint image
    cv::Mat dst;
    bh2Rad(&img,&dst);
}

void bh2Rad(Mat* srcMat,cv::Mat* dstMat)
{
    for (int i=0; i < srcMat->rows ;i++)
    {
        float* srcP = srcMat->data.fl + srcMat->width * i;// srcMat Error.
        float* dstP = dstMat->data.fl + dstMat->width * i;//dstMat Error

        for (int j = 0; j < srcMat->cols ;j++)
            dstP[j] = srcP[j] * BH_DEG_TO_RAD;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you include `Mat.h`?

Comment: What errors? Where are they?

Comment: is the "data" in "srcMat->data" a pointer?

Comment: The error is cv::Mat*srcMat. "Expression must have a class type"

Comment: can you explain, why you are trying to change an *image* from deg to rad ? it would only make sense with angles and float data.

Comment: I'm trying to plot the orientation map of a fingerprint. Here's the link. http://answers.opencv.org/question/3433/orientation-smoothing/





I'm having trouble with the orientation map for 3 weeks now.

I tried to plot it using this but the lines are all haywire http://answers.opencv.org/question/9493/fingerprint-orientation-map-through-gradient/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to confuse the older(c-api) CvMat with cv::Mat with the pixel-operations.

also, a grayscale image is uchar, not float, and you can't access its pixels in an arbitrary format (unless you convertTo() float before).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("original.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  cv::Mat dst;

  bh2Rad(img,dst);

}

//
// please use references with cv::Mat, not pointers.
// those things are refcounted, you're thrashing that with passing pointers.
//
void bh2Rad(const cv::Mat & srcMat, cv::Mat & dstMat)
{
  dstMat.create(srcMat.size(),srcMat.type());
  for (int i=0; i < srcMat.rows ;i++)
  {
    const uchar* srcP = srcMat.ptr<uchar>(i);
    uchar* dstP = dstMat.ptr<uchar>(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < srcMat.cols ;j++)
        dstP[j] = srcP[j] * BH_DEG_TO_RAD;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. i m still having the errors. firstly, why const Mat? Btw, if i changed the const Mat to only Mat, i still have error which is src->rows and src->cols

Comment: If i used const Mat, it gives an error of "a value of type "const uchar" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type *uchar.

Comment: lol, sorry again, you're about right. with a const Mat, the uchar* has to be const, too. again, my error ;(

Comment: btw berak, I think i saw u before in the opencv forum. Can u please provide me a good link to draw an orientation map? I have a dateline due in 2 weeks =(

Comment: and again, in the example above, there's not much sense in converting *uchar* values from deg to rad, right ?

Comment: ok thanks man. Btw one more question. dstMat.ptr<float>(i) is the same usage with dstMat->data.fl*i right?

Comment: yup. If i change it from uchar to float then only get the rad from degree, it makes sense right?

Comment: with an old CvMat, dstMat->data.fl is a float pointer to the 1st pixel.  whith cv::Mat, dstMat.ptr<float>(i) points to the beginning of *row* i. (e.g, it gets padding or ROIs right)

Comment: well, yes. but above will only work *if* your srcMat has float type. if you load images, you'll have to convert them before.

Comment: and about your fingerprints, maybe ask a new question, with the state where you're now ? (and also some code/pics, etc ?)

Comment: I tried my code on the pastebin, but it stopped working. Maybe like what u said, i should convert my image to float first

Comment: about my fingerprints. I have no progress although i tried several few. Didn't save those codes as it failed. And this is the post that you've edited for me ~ http://answers.opencv.org/question/30838/orientation-map-sobelhistogram/

Comment: ok now i look stupid. sorry. The mat is suppose to be a matrix full with the image gradients from Sobel operator. Then only i use these functions to convert it into degree/rad etc. It makes sense now right? I haven't been having much sleep =/

Answer (score 1):

The error marks the only instance where you didn't qualify Mat with the namespace CV. I assume you don't have a using-directive for namespace CV, therefore the type Mat which is declared only in CV is unknown and not recognized.

```
void bh2Rad(cv::Mat* srcMat, cv::Mat* dstMat)
```

(note the **cv::** directly after the opening bracket).

Comment: Thanks but i used "using namespace cv" at the beginning already. Sorry for the confusion